# Predicate logic proof

Tags: logic, proof

I need to prove: ∀xRax → ∀x∃yRyx

My available axioms are:

1. ϕ → (Ψ→ϕ )
2. (ϕ → (Ψ→χ)) → ((ϕ→Ψ) → (ϕ→χ)
3. (~Ψ→~ϕ) → ((~Ψ→ϕ) →Ψ)
4. ∀αϕ→ϕ(β / α)
5. ∀α(ϕ→Ψ) → (ϕ→∀αΨ)

Our rules are modus ponens and universal generalization.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

From Ax.4, by *Contraposition* and using the abbreviation of **¬∀¬** with **∃** we can prove :

> **ϕ(t / x)→∃xϕ**.

Now :

1) **⊢ ∀xRax → Rab** --- Ax.4

2) **∀xRax** --- premise [a]

3) **Rab** --- from 1) and 2) by *Modus Ponens*

4) **⊢ Rab → ∃yRay** --- from Ax.4

5) **∃yRay** --- from 3) and 4) by *Modus Ponens*

6) **∀x∃yRxy** --- from 5) by *Universal Generalization*

> 7) **∀xRax → ∀x∃yRxy** --- from 2) and 6) by *Deduction Theorem*.

Comment: How do we get to step 4 from contraposition and axiom 4?

Comment: @RyanT. - deriving with 1)-3) the necessary tautologies : **(p → q) → (¬q → ¬p)**.

Comment: So we can get: ~ϕ(β / α)→~∀αϕ from contraposition, but how does this lead to ϕ(β / α)→∃αϕ ?

Comment: @RyanT. - NO; you have to consider the axiom **⊢ ∀y¬Ray → ¬Rab**, contrapose it to get : **⊢ ¬¬Rab→¬∀y¬Ray** and then use Double Negation and the abbreviation to get : **⊢ Rab→∃yRay**.